# Loading time of a double link css file

Tags: html, css, performance

I have this client that wants me to make him only with HTML and CSS all in this 2 files three table designs.Tables that are different in content and in number of rows. So that he in the future to be able to easily change the table displayed or the design of the table regarding the background-color, table borders, Font Awesome images, etc. ...
So, I think that the best solution it would be to create the structure in html and design them separately in 3 different CSS files. Rather then to design them in the same file and use 3 classes (for every element that needs to be shown or hidden)
My questions is in the fact that I write aprox. 300 lines of HTML code for this 3 tables and every time the browser reads my page will be showing only one table, 100 (just to say).... How this will affect my loading time of the page. Considering that this table will not be the only element to be displayed, maybe there will be images, videos....

Thanks!

Comment: Write the code, check loading times: if it's too slow, look into optimisation techniques, if not, it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it will affect loading time.

It affects load time because it will add to the overall size of the document and affect the download time for the html and css file.

That being said, 300 lines of code may not make a significant difference in your load times as much as adding images / videos.  Probably best to build it and do your own testing to see if it's worth splitting into 3 sets of files.